# Comparing elements in each row of a matrix and count the similar values

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix like this:

```
 line=[1 3 5 0 0 4 2; 
       1 3 8 0 8 2 2 ]
```

I want to compare the rows in this matrix. If the 1st column of the first row is the same as 1st column of second row then increase a counter. But if the value is zero, then the counter should not be increased.

For the example above I expect the output to be match = 3 
where the matching values are 1,3,2 so the match = 3

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO, what have you tried to solve this problem or where are you failling in doing so?

Answer (score 2):

I would go for this:

```matlab
match = sum((line(1, :) == line(2, :)) & (line(1, :) != 0))
```

The [Array comparison](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-comparison-with-relational-operators.html#bu48dik) `line(1, :) == line(2, :)` will give you (logical) `1` at the points, where both rows have identical values:

```matlab
ans =
  1  1  0  1  0  0  1
```

Next, you need to exclude possible `0` values. That can be done by findind non-zero elements just in the first row (`line(1, :) != 0`), and then using the [`&`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/and.html#bu44441-4) operator on the results. You'll get:

```matlab
ans =
  1  1  0  0  0  0  1
```

At last, you just have to count the ones using [`sum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the sum of each column divided by the first line equal 2.

So:

```
count = sum(sum(x)./x(1,:)==2)
```

Since `0/0` is indetermined, 0 will not be taken into account.